# ISPConfig User Management Caveat? Systemd/cgroup user.slice ignored

Tags: linux, debian, cpu

This is specifically for folks using the latest ISPConfig.

I have a nextcloud installation in a jailkit, which work perfectly, except that it is CPU heavy.

**Problem** user-${UID}.slice is ignored

In ISPConfig linux rule of "1 unique user-id per username" seems to be violated, ISPConfig users will recognize this:

```
#cat /etc/passwd
web6:x:7886:7886::/var/www/clients/client8/web6/./home/web6:/usr/sbin/jk_chrootsh
adifferentusername:x:7886:7886::/var/www/clients/client8/web6/./home/adifferentusername:/usr/sbin/jk_chrootsh
```

According to debian manages I ***should*** be able to create a `CPUQuota=` value and limit user web6's CPU usage by running:

`#systemctl set-property user-7886.slice CPUQuota=35%`  && `systemctl start user-7886.slice`  && `systemcrl daemon-reload`

Which is **successful**, as verified by `systemctl cat user-7886.slice` , having
this content:

```
# /etc/systemd/system.control/user-7886.slice.d/50-CPUAccounting.conf
# This is a drop-in unit file extension, created via "systemctl set-property"
# or an equivalent operation. Do not edit.
[Slice]
CPUAccounting=yes

# /etc/systemd/system.control/user-7886.slice.d/50-CPUQuota.conf
# This is a drop-in unit file extension, created via "systemctl set-property"
# or an equivalent operation. Do not edit.
[Slice]
CPUQuota=35%

# /etc/systemd/system.control/user-7886.slice.d/50-CPUWeight.conf
# This is a drop-in unit file extension, created via "systemctl set-property"
# or an equivalent operation. Do not edit.
[Slice]
# /usr/lib/systemd/system/user-.slice.d/10-defaults.conf
#  SPDX-License-Identifier: LGPL-2.1+
#
#  This file is part of systemd.
#
#  systemd is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it
#  under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as published by
#  the Free Software Foundation; either version 2.1 of the License, or
#  (at your option) any later version.
```

Despite the correct settings necessary to limit a user's CPU usage as shown above, whenever the nextcloud installation located at the /var/www/clients/client8/web6/web directory (remember "web6" is also a system user), executes a sync function it is still able to use unlimited CPU.

I have temporarily placed a CPUQuota directly on php7.4-fpm that nextcloud and all of  apps use (wordpress /drupal etc) via adding `CPUQuota=45%` directly to `#nano /usr/lib/systemd/system/php7.4-fpm.service`.  Illustrating that `CPUQuota` (systemd/cgroup) is functioning properly, but ISPConfig's unique linux user configuration appears to interfere with / prevent systemd/cgroup from properly  appyling user.${UID}.slice properties.

Has anyone else found a solution to limit CPU usage per ISPConfig user using debian/ubuntu systemd v241?